# Поиск евклидова расстояния между всеми парами векторов

Tags: python, анализ-данных

Есть N-количество векторов m-размерности (обычные флоат числа от -1 до 1 в виде списка списков). Нужно найти векторы с наибольшим и наименьшим расстоянием (их номера и расстояние). А затем сделать график распределения расстояний. Но проблема в том, запрещено создавать структуры данных больше чем N x m элементов. Я понимаю, как это решается обычным перебором всех пар, но незнаком с библиотеками, которые могут помочь это сделать с таким ограничением по памяти

UPD
Output: максимальное расстояние (и индексы векторов), минимальное расстоние (опять же +индексы), изображение гистограммы распределения расстояний с шагом 0.1

```
500 < N <= 1000
10 < m <= 50
```

Comment: наверное задание в том, чтобы реализовать нужный перебор самому, а не искать подходящую библиотеку

Comment: @Viktorov, нет, это не так.

Comment: А  `N^2  >  N * m`?

Comment: @MBo да, в несколько раз

Comment: Ну так стоит это указать, иначе ограничение `N x m` неполноценное. Кроме того, нужно объяснить, что такое `график распределения расстояний`

Comment: @MBo спасибо за совет

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что Python здесь ни при чем.

```
vector min1 = vectors[0], min2 = vectors[1];
double min = distance(min1, min2);
vector max1 = vectors[0], max2 = vectors[1];
double max = distance(max1, max2);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
    double d = distance(vectors[i], vectors[j]);
    if (d > max) {
      max1 = vectors[i];
      max2 = vectors[j];
      max = d;
    }
    if (d < min) {
      min1 = vectors[i];
      min2 = vectors[j];
      min = d;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, Python указан не просто так, во-вторых, это решение никак не приближает к тому, чтобы получить график распределения расстояний.

Comment: В дополнение : после вычисления `d` можно обновить гистограмму `hist[(int) d/10 ]++;`, где `hist = [0] * (10 * 2 * m)`  (подразумевается, что distance в пределах `-m..m`, как скалярное произведение)